# How to serve compressed content without caching in AWS Cloudfront with API Gateway origin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, content-negotiation

I'm using Cloudfront distribution with Regional API Gateway origin. For endpoints, for which I can't use caching, I still need the response body to be compressed, if request includes "Accept-Encoding" header.

That's such a trivial requirement, and I think I have tried everything:

- "Fake" caching policy with TTL=0 doesn't allow compression to be turned on.
- API Gateway compression doesn't work without Accept-Encoding header passed, and Cloudfront never allows to pass it.
- Origin request policy doesn't allow to pass custom Accept-Encoding header.
- Origin request policy with "All viewer headers" doesn't work, because API Gateway doesn't like the Host header. Setting up custom domain is not working together with Cloudfront using same domain.
- Origin doesn't allow to add custom Accept-Encoding header.

Well, after trying everything, I already expect that's not possible **for a reason**. But I don't understand why.

Please, explain me, what's so bad in compressing non-cached responses?

Or is there a chance I can do this?

**UPD**

Cloufront functions are not allowed with origin requests

In Lambda@Edge functions Accept-Encoding is read-only.

Comment: "Make sure the TTL values in the cache policy are set to a value greater than zero. When you set the TTL values to zero, caching is disabled and CloudFront doesn’t compress objects. " https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#compressed-content-cloudfront-configuring

Comment: So, it seems to be by design.  Have you tried using Lambda@Edge or Cloud Functions to preserve headings?

Comment: @Norman yes, everything I've tried is by design, I was able to find information after I was getting an error. Functions/Edge - next thing to try, will leave a line here, but what the heck!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable caching but you could set a low TTL of 1 second and then add a header like `X-Amz-Cf-Id` to your cache policy to act like a cache buster. Since the value of `X-Amz-Cf-Id` is unique to each request it will effectively disable caching.

> CloudFront adds the `X-Amz-Cf-Id` header to the viewer request before forwarding the request to your origin. The header value contains an encrypted string that uniquely identifies the request.

Comment: Actually caching based on that header values is not supported